# I get the following error, Failed to instantiate module starter due to: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ngMessages

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

```
angular.module('starter')
 .controller('RegSalesCtrl', function($scope, $ionicModal, $http, $timeout,$state, ionicMaterialMotion, ionicMaterialInk) 
var address = localStorage.getItem('address');
console.log(address);
$scope.getSale = function (){
 $http.get(address+"api/getRegisterSale").success(function (data){
                 $scope.saleData = data.data;     
           }).error(function (data){
                 $scope.error = data;
                console.log($scope.error);
           });
};
$scope.getSale();
```

The following error comes

> SyntaxError: expected expression, got '.' .controller('AddSalesCtrl',
>   function($scope, Camera, $timeou..

However injector module error i don't seem to understand what to do

Comment: so you have an error in `AddSalesCtrl` controller and you provide us with `RegSalesCtrl` huh?

Comment: in this controller you are missing `{` here `.controller('RegSalesCtrl', function($scope, $ionicModal, $http, $timeout,$state, ionicMaterialMotion, ionicMaterialInk)`

Comment: No..I sorted AddSalesCtrl issue. What is left is injector.modulerr..

Answer (score 0):

You will need to inject ngMessages module into you app, like this

`angular.module('starter', ['ngMessages']).controller(...)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that 'ngMessage' module is available eg:

```
angular.module('starter', ['ngMessages']);
```

Additionally check that you have the script too:

```
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-rc.0/angular-messages.js"></script>
```

Have a look at this example:

http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers. The bower component for ngMessages was missing and it worked wen I installed it.